# How to change Region / Zone in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am very new to Google Cloud. I was able to setup a wordpress site and am working on it now. However, it appears that my vm instance is using the following asia-east1-a   for its zone. I was able to change the Region and Zone using gcloud commands with the following output:

```
$ gcloud config list compute/region 
Your active configuration is: [default]
[compute]
region = us-east4

$ gcloud config list compute/zone
Your active configuration is: [default]
[compute]
zone = us-east4-b
```

How does one change the active default to the new set zone? I would like my instance to run in the North East Coast of the USA?

Thanks,
T

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/changing-default-zone-region

Answer (score 62):

Use commands below at cloud shell.

To check your preferred region:

```
$ gcloud compute regions list
```

To change compute regions, I select `us-east4` region:

```
$ gcloud config set compute/region us-east4
```

Updated property [compute/region].

```
$ gcloud config list compute/region
```

[compute]

```
region = us-east4
```

In a similar way, you can change compute/zone.

Answer (score 11):

- As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#default-properties), `project-info` metadata can be added per project to specify the default regions and zones. This is used only at the time of initializing `gcloud` (using `gcloud init`).
- In addition, `gcloud` supports locally setting the default region and zone using the `compute/region` and `compute/zone` configurations (which is what you seem to have added to your local gcloud config). When these properties are set, they will override any configuration set in the `project-info`.
- Since you have set these properties according to your requirements, I think your defaults are set as long as you're using that gcloud configuration.
- Do remember that you can always override the `zone` and `region` using the `--zone` and `--region` arguments to any of the `gcloud` commands.

### [Moving instance from one zone to another](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones)

Changing the default zone/region does not move any of the existing VMs to a new zone. If you wish to [move a VM from one zone to another](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones), you can take a snapshot of the persistent disks, launch a new instance in the desired zone using the snapshot and cleanup the resources used by the original VM.

You can do this using either `gcloud` or follow a set of steps manually to achieve the same result.

```
gcloud compute instances move INSTANCE_NAME --zone SOURCE_ZONE --destination-zone DESTINATION_ZONE
```

> In detail, Compute Engine will:
>
> - Take snapshots of persistent disks attached to the source instance.
> - Create copies of the persistent disks in the destination zone.
> - For instances moving within the same region, temporarily promote any ephemeral external IP addresses assigned to the instance to a static
>     external IP address.
> - Create a new instance in the destination zone.
> - Attach the newly created persistent disks to your new instance.
> - Assign an external IP address to the new instance. If necessary, demote the address back to an ephemeral external IP address.
> - Delete the snapshots, original disks, and original instance.
>
> If you want to manually move your instance, you can also perform these
>   steps by hand.

Comment: k, so the settings that I have changed are correct. Do I have to restart the VM or initiate a move or anything? Without losing the work / setup that I have already done? Do I just clone it to the new region and zone? I am very sorry if this seems obvious as I am very new to GCloud.

Thanks,
T

Comment: Added info about moving an instance from one zone to another.

Comment: K, I think I am close. I was able to run the command; however, it failed with:

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.move) Instances belonging to subnetworks cannot be moved interregionally.

I have tried to change / delete the subnet (I do not care about internal or external IP - this instance is not in use yet and I can update DNS later).

But it will not let me delete any subnet or change anything under networking? 

Any ideas?

PS: Thank you so much for helping out...

Comment: @Tuxdude what about that case : `Instance is a UEFI-enabled instance and does not support MoveInstance.` ?

Comment: This method did not work for me. I also returned an error `Instance is a UEFI-enabled instance and does not support MoveInstance.`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't remember the specific commands, another option is to change the region and zone in the gcloud configurations file which is located in:

```
~/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default
```

And contain the structure below:

```
[core]
account = my-account@my-domain
project = my-project

[compute]
zone = asia-south1-a
region = asia-south1
```

After changing region to `us-central-1` you'll get the following output:

```
gcloud config list compute/region
[compute]
region = us-central1

gcloud config configurations list
NAME     IS_ACTIVE  ACCOUNT               PROJECT     COMPUTE_DEFAULT_ZONE  COMPUTE_DEFAULT_REGION
default  True       my-account@my-domain  my-project  us-central1-a         us-central1
```

---

[Reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones) to all GCP regions and zones.

Answer (score 2):

Create Image of the existing instance and after create a new instance with a new zone who you like and uploaded this image with you create before

Answer (score 0):

```
gcloud compute instances move INSTANCE_NAME --destination-zone=DESTINATION_ZONE [--async] [--zone=ZONE] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]
```

gcloud compute instances move facilitates moving a Compute Engine virtual machine from one zone to another.

EXAMPLE :

```
gcloud compute instances move compute-instance-1 --zone us-central1-b --destination-zone us-central1-f
```