# the zone does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request/ the resource is not ready

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I failed to start my instance (through the web browser), it gave me the error:

> "The zone 'projects/XXXXX/zones/europe-west4-b' does not have enough
>   resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or
>   try again later."

I thought it might be the quota problem at first, after checking my quota, it showed all good. Actually, I listed the available zones, europe-west4-b was available, but I still gave a shot to move the zone. Then I tried  `"gcloud compute instances move XXXX --zone europe-west4-b --destination-zone europe-west4-c"`, however, it still failed, popped up the error:

> "ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.move) Instance cannot be moved while
>   in state: TERMINATED"

Okay, terminated... then I tried to restart it by `"gcloud compute instances reset XXX"`, the error showed in the way:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.reset) Could not fetch resource:
>    - The resource 'projects/XXXXX/zones/europe-west4-b/instances/XXX'
>   is not ready

I searched the error, some people solved this problem by deleting the disk. While I don't want to wipe the memory, how could I solve this problem?

BTW, I only have one instance, with one persistent disk attached.

Comment: I tried it 6 hours later, then it works fine. = =

Comment: This is the best way to reslove this error https://stackoverflow.com/a/45126763/9243066

Comment: Still 4 years on, same problem. BTW very legitimate question. Expect Google to provide a solution for this issue.

Comment: @W.M. I’m guessing you got screwed today too? The easiest thing I came up with was to click the instance, click “create similar” and then choose a different location. I now have them as backups in case this happens again.

Comment: Yes, that was the "solution". To create it in another region.

Answer (score 55):

Even I'm getting the same error. I have waited for 24 hours and tried. But still no luck.
For me, it's not transient.

> The zone 'projects/XXXX/zones/europe-west2-c' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

I had to create entirely new instance to come over it.

Comment: I upvoted because you gave a solution to my problem, but this is the kind of bug someone on the GCloud really ought to fix.  All love to Google and the people providing the service: I'm very grateful for it.  But I really don't want to have to redo these hours of work

Answer (score 38):

So I had the same issue for over 24 hours.

I tried to move my VM to another zone, but since it was in the terminated state and I couldn't restart it due to not having enough resources in my region, I couldn't move it.

Okay, but then per my understanding, your persistent disk attached to your VM is another story and you can copy it without starting your VM.

So I went around this issue by:

1. Going to my Google Cloud Platform >>> Compute Engine
2. Went to Snapshots >>> created a snapshot >>> Select your Compute Engine instance
3. Once snapshot was completed I clicked on my snapshot.
4. Ended up under "snapshot details". There, on the top, just click create instance. Here you are basically creating an instance with a copy of your disk.
5. Select your new zone, don't forget to attach GPUs, all previous setting, create new name.
6. Click create, that's it, your image should now be running in your new zone

Comment: Do you need to remove the snapshot afterwards to avoid any storage charges associated with it?

Comment: from what I understand depending where (which region) you create your snapshot in, you may incur network costs when you redeploy.  

--- https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots

then regrading storing your snapshot on persistent disk attached to your VM, from what I see, I think you will be charged (per GB/month stored), according to this pricing list:

https://cloud.google.com/persistent-disk/

Comment: Selecting your snapshot storage location is vital to minimizing network costs. If you store your snapshot in the same region as your source disk there is no network charge when you access that snapshot from the same region. If you access the snapshot from a different region, there is a network cost.
.
As of 08/16
Snapshot storage (GB/MONTH) = $0.026
Multi-regional snapshot storage in each multi-region = $0.026

Comment: I ran into the same problem today and this answer saved me. Thanks!

Comment: Note: when I did this, I lost permissions to my gcloud storage buckets

Comment: @AbdullahTahan did you select "new" zone? What didn't work? Perhaps have to try multiple zones before you find one that has available capacity.

Comment: i had really stuck in that as we were using regional ip and was used in the mobile app so we need the same or new instance in that region but google didn't allow me todo that so that solution didn't work if i want to create new instance from snapshop to that region

Answer (score 11):

As others have noted, this occurs when a GCP zone is oversubscribed, and its generally temporary.  There is something that you can do to defend against it happening to you in the future though.

What it almost certainly won't resolve the error while the zone has insufficient resources, you can prevent this error in the future by [Reserving Zonal Resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) in advance -- effectively guaranteeing that the resources will be available for you when you need them.

Of course, as you are asking GCP to hold computing resources for your future use, you are billed for the instance reservation as if it was a fully running instance (but there isn't an additional charge while your instance is actually running).  They also qualify for [sustained use](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#sustained_use) and [committed use](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#committed_use) discounts like any VM instance.

There's a lot of configurability in what you can reserve, but the minimal gcloud command to reserve a single instance might look something like this:

```
gcloud compute reservations create my-reservation --machine-type=n1-standard-1 --zone=us-central1-a --vm-count=1
```

And to delete it when you are done:

```
gcloud compute reservations delete my-reservation
```

You can also do this through the console, on the 'Compute Engine > Commited use discounts > Reservations' tab.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me over the weekend when I wanted to swap the K80 to a new P100 instance.

### My setup:

- 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' quota is set to 1.
- A single GPU (K80) instance on europe-west1 (zone: europe-west1-b)

#### Steps that produced the error:

1. Deleted the K80 instance.
2. After deleting I had a total of 0 instances running.
3. Each attempt to create a new instance in the same region produced the error message.

Any instance created on other regions with the same zone identifier ('b', from europe-west1-b) produced this error as well.

---

### How to resolve this issue:

Create a GPU instance **on a different region and a different zone identifier** ('a', 'c', 'd', ...). That's it.

Answer (score 0):

To have a more up to date answer, today I had the same issue with the zone us-central1-a. I was getting the error message "The zone 'projects//zones/us-central1-a' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. '(resource type:compute)'.". Fortunatelly the error was overcome by just waiting 5 minutes and trying again.

Comment: I just had this same issue with the same zone, my solution was to downgrade the number of CPUs from 2 --> 1. I tried all day with 2 CPUs and I just lowered to 1 CPU and it started without issue. I have GPU enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Starting the instance using the GUI instead worked for me. Seems like a bug in `gcloud`.