# Google Compute Engine ALL zones lack resources

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to restart some VMs in different zones on Google Compute Engine. I don't use this for industrial tasks, but for some ML research tasks that I can't do on my laptop.

Over the last three days, when I try to start my VMs I get the message

```
The zone <WHATEVER ZONE I TRY> does not have enough 
resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or 
try again later
```

If I try to create new VM I get the same message. Is there something I'm doing wrong? What's going on here?

If there's more information that it would be helpful for me to provide, please let me know.

Comment: same issue here - I've tried multiple zones across europe and all the sub zones for each one (a, b, c, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [the zone does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request/ the resource is not ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684656/the-zone-does-not-have-enough-resources-available-to-fulfill-the-request-the-re)

Comment: Most likely a transitory issue ... also note the duplicate reference.  I suggest closing this question so that others don't spend time here.

Comment: Are you a free-trial user? Are you attempting to create a VM with GPUs or a machine type other than from the N1 family?  There are certain restrictions for free-trial users that can be circumvented by upgrading the account. However it would be the best if you check what type of issue is causing this, check Activity (in the dashboard) and see if you get any quota related message as well.