# GCP: Instance creation failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, quota

I recently tried to create an instance group on the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) with 50 `n1-standard-1` instances in zone `us-east1-b`, each with `P100` GPUs. I requested and got approval for `200` P100 GPUs in this zone. My `CPU`, `IP addresses`, and `Routes` for this zone and globally all meet the quotas listed on this page.

However, right now, I'm only up to 21 of these 50 instances created, with the rest with a yellow hazard sign and the accompanying warning message: `Instance 'instance-group-1-<name>' creation failed: The zone 'projects/<project>/zones/us-east1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. '(resource type:compute)'.`

Is there any place on the quotas page where I can get information on exactly which `compute` quota I forgot to ask more of? The error message is unfortunately not very descriptive.

Note: I suspect that this could be a reference to exceeding the Compute Engine API query limiting access to at most `2000` querues per `100` seconds. The `7 day peak usage` column does show that I have exceeded it at peak times. However, my `Current Usage` is at less than `70` queries per `1000` seconds. When I look at my compute engine query usage graphed over time, it doesn't look like I have tripped the `2000` rate limit for several hours. However, the instance group still fails to populate fully to all `50` instances.

Answer (score 6):

This is a typical error which means that at a certain point in time, the resources in 'us-east1-b' are not sufficient to scale your Instance Group even though you have sufficient quota. You have two alternatives:

1- try again later
2- request GPUs in another region/zone and deploy your IG there.

Google also recommends to distribute your workloads in more than one region and zone.

For more information see [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#quotas_and_resource_availability) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684656/the-zone-does-not-have-enough-resources-available-to-fulfill-the-request-the-re).