# Google Compute Engine GPU: "not enough resources available to fulfill the request" on ANY region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've been having trouble the past few days with starting up any VM with a GPU on the Google Compute Engine. I've tried many different zones from the US regions as well as Europe regions with no success. I also can't seem to create a new VM and I am only using 1 GPU.

I've encountered this problem before but it never persists for this long. I have not changed anything with my VMs either and it's been working fine before this.

Has anyone experienced this, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any quota restrictions. Please check in quota page or do 'gcloud compute project-info describe --project myproject'

Comment: I have 2 GPUs for all zones in my quotas page. I am sure this isn't the case because I have been able to spin up the VM before without any problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the zone does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request/ the resource is not ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684656/the-zone-does-not-have-enough-resources-available-to-fulfill-the-request-the-re)

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I have tried all the options there including trying to create instances in different zones or moving my current instance to different zones. 

In the past I can wait a few hours or a day and it would work again, but this time it's been many days and still no luck.  

Also been seeing some more of these problems popping up for other people so I'm not sure what's going on?