# Google Compute returns "Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded" when spinning up a GPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We are in need to onboard a client to our project and we need a GPU enabled instance. In each and every US region where I am trying to spin up a GPU instance the below error is  thrown:

```
The zone /zones/us-east4-c' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

Create VM instance "instance-1" and its boot disk "instance-1"
5 minutes ago

Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally

The zone 'projects/zones/us-central1-f' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
The zone 'projects//zones/us-central1-f' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.

The zone 'projects//zones/us-central1-c' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

I have a GPU Quota of 1 enabled for all these regions. Not sure why below error popped out:

```
Create VM instance "instance-1" and its boot disk "instance-1"
5 minutes ago

Quota 'GPUS_ALL_REGIONS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 globally
```

What can we do to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the zone does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request/ the resource is not ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684656/the-zone-does-not-have-enough-resources-available-to-fulfill-the-request-the-re)

Comment: What is your GCE quota for "GPUs (all regions)"?

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible that the zone just doesn't have enough physical resources to fulfill the request. 
I do see `Limit: 0.0 globally`, however, which tells me that across all regions you are allowed to have 0 GPUs. Even if you have the appropriate quota left in us-central1 you wouldn't be able to spin up a GPU instance because the global quota is too low (both quotas get used for this).