# The region europe-west3 does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Please try again later

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We are getting more often than not the error message when deploying to Google App Engine - GAE:
`The region europe-west3 does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Please try again later.`

We have been getting this for a while and sometimes, like today, making it impossible to deploy for a whole morning, it's really inconvenient.

I have seen a different post that is more than 2 years old:
[the zone does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request/ the resource is not ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684656/the-zone-does-not-have-enough-resources-available-to-fulfill-the-request-the-re)

Google says they work on avoiding this but we run into it constantly. Is any one else facing the same issues in 2021? Or has found a way to avoid it?

Thanks!

Comment: You can create a [reservation with Committed use discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources#combining_reservations_with_committed_use_discounts) to reserve Compute Engine zonal resources, to ensure resources are available for your workloads when you need them. There are [limitations and restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources#limitations_and_restrictions)  you have to know before you create it. 
You can use public issue tracker to see if there's an outage versus a regular stockout.

Comment: @MisterMonk - Which machine type are you using for your VMs? I only see this issue with shared core VMs and not with the larger sizes.