# Google VM Instance failing to start

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

The google VM instance for region europe-west4-b, is failing to start today, It was working fine till yesterday, I receive an error message when I click on start as following:

```
Failed to start ubuntu-2: The zone 'projects/XXX/zones/europe-west4-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. '(resource type:compute)'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the zone does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request/ the resource is not ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684656/the-zone-does-not-have-enough-resources-available-to-fulfill-the-request-the-re)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue, let me provide you some explanations:

1. When you [stop an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance) it releases some resources like vCPU and memory.
2. When you [start an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stop-start-instance#starting_a_stopped_instance) (or change it) it requests resources like vCPU and memory back and if there's not enough resources available in the zone you'll get an error message. More information available in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-instances#vm-not-created):

   > If you receive a resource error (such as ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED
   > or ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED_WITH_DETAILS) when requesting new
   > resources, it means that the zone cannot currently accommodate your
   > request. **This error is due to Compute Engine resource obtainability,
   > and is not due to your Compute Engine quota**.
3. Resource availability are depending from users requests and therefore are dynamic.

**There are a few ways to solve such issue** without moving it to another zone:

1. [Move your VM instance to another zone](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/moving-instance-across-zones) if it's possible in your use case.
2. Wait for a while and try to start your VM instance again.
3. [Reserve resources](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) for your VM by following documentation to avoid such issue in future (extra payment required).