# The region asia-northeast2 does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Please try again later

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, app.yaml

I kept getting this error. I already tried deploying to gcp more than 6 hours. Is there any solution for this without just waiting?

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: 
[9] Flex operation projects/XXX/regions/asia-northeast2/operations/XXX error 
[FAILED_PRECONDITION]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/flex_await_healthy/flex_await_healthy>XXX: 
The region asia-northeast2 does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. 
Please try again later.
```

Here is my app.yaml file

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

automatic_scaling:
    max_num_instances: 2

env_variables:
    SQL_USER: XXX
    SQL_PASSWORD: XXX
    SQL_DATABASE: XXX
    INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME: XXX:asia-northeast2:XXX

beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: XXX:asia-northeast2:XXX
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the zone does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request/ the resource is not ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684656/the-zone-does-not-have-enough-resources-available-to-fulfill-the-request-the-re)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you’re facing is due to the availability of the resources in asia-northeast2.

To solve this I suggest you to check this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1003351/701350).

Additionally, you can also try the following options:

- Wait until the resources of asia-northeast2 are available again.
- You can change from Flex Environment to Standard Environment and when prompted select another region to deploy it.
- Run the project in another product (Cloud Run, GKE... ).