# I can't resize the disk with Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I try to increase the disk size of my VM I get this error: Operation type [resize] failed with message "The zone 'projects/*****/zones/europe-west1-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request. Try a different zone, or try again later."

How can I solve this?

Comment: Nothing to do, wait for new resources. It can happen anytime. there are workloads (of another customer) that use temporarily disk. When the disk are released, you will be able to get some space.

Comment: Your question lack details. What is the size you are trying to allocate? Does your project have a sufficient quota to allocate that size? https://cloud.google.com/compute/resource-usage How are you resizing (web console GUI or via the CLI)? The CLI will often report better error details to clarify the problem and solution. Given that you do have a sufficient quota, the solution might be to wait - try during the late evening due to many customers shutting down systems in the PM.

Comment: One additional item, what is the instance size? Small sizes are in high demand. Resizing to a larger instance size sometimes works.

Answer (score 1):

As from your question I could figure out that resources unavailable for the `europe-west1-b` zone possibly due to the type and size of VM that you requested is currently unavailable in the zone that you requested it in.

**Refer to official GCP [Troubleshooting resource availability errors](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-resource-availability#reasons-recommendations) :**

> Resource errors occur when you try to request resources in a zone that
> cannot accommodate your request due to the current unavailability of a
> Compute Engine resource, such as GPUs or CPUs.
>
> The best way to resolve a resource error is to
> **retry the request in a different zone, at a different time, or with a different VM configuration or try again later.**
>
> **If you're requesting multiple VMs, try one or more of the following:**
>
> 1. Request the VMs in another zone.
> 2. If your workload permits, request a zonal or regional SSD persistent disk instead of local SSD.
> 3. Split your local SSD request into multiple VMs. For example, if you requested one VM with 600GB of local SSD, divide the request into
>    several VMs that have a total combined local SSD of 600GB.

There are a few [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52684656) & [SF](https://serverfault.com/questions/1016898) which addresses similar issues. Please have a look at these, which will give you more relevant information about your issue.

Comment: This part solves the issue for me almost 100% of the time: `The best way to resolve a resource error is to retry the request in a different zone, at a different time, or with a different VM configuration or try again later.`