# gcloud Property validation was skipped

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

I am using gcloud CLI to configure my region and zone:

```
gcloud config set compute/region us-central1
gcloud config set compute/zone us-central1-c
```

But each command lasts for about 15 seconds, and I get a warning:

```
WARNING: Property validation for compute/region was skipped
```

Everything works fine, but why do I have 15 seconds delay, and a warning?

With verbose argument, the output is:

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.config.set] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug", SECTION/PROPERTY: "compute/region", VALUE: "us-central1"]
Updated property [compute/region].
DEBUG: Making request: GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/GOOGLE_AACOUNT_REPLACED@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com/?recursive=true
DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): metadata.google.internal:80
DEBUG: http://metadata.google.internal:80 "GET /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/GOOGLE_AACOUNT_REPLACED@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com/?recursive=true HTTP/1.1" 200 185
DEBUG: Making request: GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/GOOGLE_AACOUNT_REPLACED@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com/token
DEBUG: http://metadata.google.internal:80 "GET /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/GOOGLE_AACOUNT_REPLACED@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com/token HTTP/1.1" 200 1050
DEBUG: Making request: GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/GOOGLE_AACOUNT_REPLACED@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com/?recursive=true
DEBUG: Starting new HTTP connection (1): metadata.google.internal:80
DEBUG: http://metadata.google.internal:80 "GET /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/GOOGLE_AACOUNT_REPLACED@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com/?recursive=true HTTP/1.1" 200 185
DEBUG: Making request: GET http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/GOOGLE_AACOUNT_REPLACED@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com/token
DEBUG: http://metadata.google.internal:80 "GET /computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/GOOGLE_AACOUNT_REPLACED@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com/token HTTP/1.1" 200 1050
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): compute.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://compute.googleapis.com:443 "POST /batch/compute/v1 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: https://compute.googleapis.com:443 "POST /batch/compute/v1 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: https://compute.googleapis.com:443 "POST /batch/compute/v1 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: https://compute.googleapis.com:443 "POST /batch/compute/v1 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: https://compute.googleapis.com:443 "POST /batch/compute/v1 HTTP/1.1" 200 None
WARNING: Property validation for compute/region was skipped.
```

Comment: Maybe add `--verbosity=debug` and rerun the command ... there might be some additional diagnostics available to us.    For a wild guess on an answer, I could imagine gcloud sending REST requests back to GCP to validate your parameters and those REST calls being blocked or failing with a 15 second timeout.

Comment: Hi, can you try to update your components using the command: [gcloud components update](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update), and check if it's working? And are you using cloud shell or running the commands locally? If locally then you may wanna check your firewall rules.

Comment: I am running this on the GCP CloudBuild platform, and using the image gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud. I believe GCP supplies an updated version, when I run gcloud version I get: Google Cloud SDK 359.0.0

Comment: Then, can you check if compute.googleapis.com api is enabled? Also provide us configuration file, check for reference in these links: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65392982/15774177, https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute#default-region-zone. Also explain your Cloudbuild set up as you are running through this, and provide us with cloudbuild.yaml file.

Comment: There is no folder of ~/.config/gcloud on the build container (gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud), so I cannot find how to supply such config as requested. The build uses the gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud container and runs a bash script that runs the command `gcloud config set compute/region us-central1`. This is required for further commands later used such as starting other build triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the gcloud tool easier to use, the Google Cloud will try and validate the values provided, including “compute/region”. In this case, it has to fetch a full list of available regions from the API. If this fails, for whatever reason, then it will show this warning message.

One of the many reasons may be that the Compute Engine API is not enabled. It could also be a lack of authentication, although Cloud Build will have authentication enabled by default and you don't need any special permissions to run this command.

To find out what exactly is going wrong, you can try adding the --log-http parameter to your gcloud command line. This will display the full details of any interactions with the API, including any error message in the response.

In any case, this is simply a warning, and the config entry is still being updated. This happens even if the validation fails, e.g. the region does not exist. As I mentioned above, this is just a feature to help letting the user know if they make certain types of simple mistakes.

Comment: I had added the roles/compute.networkViewer to the account, and it worked. The --log-http is great! BTW - I think it is a bug, the gcloud should not try 5 times the request in case it had failed on error 403 permission denied.